# How to prevent overlapping of two divs?

Tags: css

I have a page, when i am looking this page on a laptop screen the two divs are rendering properly but when i am looking this page on mobile screen these two divs are overlapping above each other. I want to remove this overlapping of these divs and want to read first div then second div.

How to do that ?

Comment: Please add some code (HTML/CSS) to your question.

Comment: have you tried something..?

Comment: share your code what you tried?

Comment: you can make those divs responsive and then try.

Comment: theres a magic trick that solves 90% of these issues; apply "display: inline-block" to those divs

Comment: Edit your question with the informations you added here in comments, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@media only screen and (max-width:768px){
.vc_row-fluid.lighter-overlay, 
.vc_row-fluid.darker-overlay{
 display:inline-block; /* Change this to inline-block instead of block */
}
}
```

but this is creating issue for header,solve that accordingly

Comment: sorry use max-width instead of min-width, i made changes in the code

Answer (score 0):

check out with Bootstrap. it provides with responsive CSS. you have to include the div class that you require.

example: if you have two divs, put them into one main div and then call each div with separate div class. like

```
<div class="col-sm-12">

<div class="col-sm-6">
// your code for first div
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6">
//your code for second div
</div>

</div>
```

try like this. it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

I hope i understand your question because its not really clear(No code provided)

But what i think you need to do is the following:

```
<!-- Probably your html part -->

<div class = "wrapper">
    <div class = "container">
        <!-- Some content-->
    </div>
    <div class = "container">
        <!-- Some content-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Here comes the css magic.....

```
.wrapper{
    display:block;
}
.container{
    display: inline-block;
}
@media only screen and (max-width:768px){
    .container{
        width:100%;
     }
}
@media only screen and (min-width:768px){
    .container{
        width:50%;
     }
}
```

By using media querys you can easily fix this kind of stuff

Comment: That is strange....can you provide me some code so i can see what the problem is? This method should normally work on all devices

Answer (score 0):

You added as a comment to your question that a demo URL was http://voyagecontrol.com/canarywharf

Origin of the problem: `#venue_draft` has inline styles including `height: 900px`.
Solution: it should be removed (elements should adapt automatically to more or less content. Not fixing height is a good start for that) or, if other problems occur, replaced by `min-height: 900px`